# Make bottom of container curvy in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I would like to make the container bottom curvy. I have tried so hard with clippath but it's been pretty difficult. I will appreciate any help
Below is the image link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Ev5aC3dsHo8a5wgWxOAu_hu2q6_ATuo/view?usp=share_link

I have tried using clip path. I could not get any accurate result. The result i got is below: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ihPG0fbx0agaeLfsgX9bBMykmba9PXdD/view?usp=share_link

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomClipPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double w = size.width;
    double h = size.height;
    int curveHeight = 5;
    Offset controlPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height + curveHeight);
    Offset endPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height - curveHeight);

    Path path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, size.height - curveHeight)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          controlPoint.dx, controlPoint.dy, endPoint.dx, endPoint.dy)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}```
````